# React function component re-renders and useRef value also disappears upon clicking 'Submit' button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component, react-state, react-state-management

The code below is my **Login.js** function component in **React**.

In my `<App.js/>`, I only render `<Login/>` component and everything seems to work until I hit 'submit' and my entire `Login.js` component re-renders and I loose all my state variables.

Even when I save the state variables inside 'credentials' useRef, it somehow disappears.

It would be really appreciated if you could tell me why my `<Login/>` component re-renders after I pass my 'email' and 'password' to the function 'handleLogin()'.

My goal is

- understand how the component life cycle is working here in my Login function component
- store the state values of email and password safely so I can use it later for
  a login authentication.

[image]
[image]

**After I click submit the component re-renders and this logs:**

[image]

```
import { React, useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Form, Button, Container } from "react-bootstrap";

export default function Login() {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

    const credentials = useRef({e:'defaulut email', p:'default password'})

    console.log('\n')
    console.log("re-render");
    console.log("email:", email);
    console.log("password:", password);

    console.log(credentials.current)

    const handleLogin = (emaill, passwordd) => {
        console.log("email:", emaill);
        console.log("password:", passwordd);

        credentials.current.e = email;
        credentials.current.p = password;

    };

    return (
        <Container className="mt-5">
            <Form>
                <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
                    <Form.Label>Email address</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                        type="email"
                        placeholder="Enter email"
                        value={email}
                        onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                    />
                    <Form.Text className="text-muted">
                        We'll never share your email with anyone else.
                    </Form.Text>
                </Form.Group>
                <Form.Group controlId="formBasicPassword">
                    <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                        type="password"
                        placeholder="Password"
                        value={password}
                        onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                    />
                </Form.Group>
                <Button
                    variant="primary"
                    type="submit"
                    onClick={() => {
                        handleLogin(email, password);
                    }}
                    >
                    Submit
                </Button>
            </Form>
        </Container>
    );
}
```

Comment: I'd propose you to refactor your submit button's handler to something with `preventDefault` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault . Something like: `onClick={(ev) => { ev.preventDefault(); ... }`. It looks like you're getting full page reload upon submitting your form.

Comment: @aleksxor hey you just solved my 4hr problem so easily! THANK YOU SO MUCH! it worked!